# Char replacement (without using replace)

Tags: java

This code is a series of tasks, the first is it replace all 'F' in sentence string to a 'f' without using the .replace() method. Which i've done, then after that I'm supposed to replace all the 'f's to blanks, which I sort of done but for some reason all my capital 'F's change to a weird square. Any ideas? I know it's basic code but baby steps.

Here is my weird output: "There was a isherman named []isher who ished or some ish in a issure; till a ish with a grin, pulled the isherman in. Now they’re ishing the issure or []isher."

Thanks! Rob.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // orginal string sentence
    String sentence = ("There was a fisherman named Fisher who fished for some fish in a fissure; till a fish with a grin, pulled the fisherman in.  Now they’re fishing the fissure for Fisher. ");
    // data
    char[] originalArray = sentence.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int sLength = sentence.length();
    int positionArray[];
    // combining an int to the array position
    positionArray = new int[sLength];
    /* while loop to check the position of any 'F' or 'f' characters in sentence and identifying it's array position*/
    while (i < sLength) {
        char charAt = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (charAt == 'F') {
            originalArray[i] = 0;
            positionArray[i] = 1;
        }
        i++;

    }
    //redeclaring int i to 0 for the new array
    i = 0;
    //reassigning the character 'F' or 'f' to just 'f to 'sentence'
    sentence = new String(originalArray);
    char[] newArray = sentence.toCharArray();
    while (i < sLength) {
        if (positionArray[i] == 1) {
            newArray[i] = 'f';
        }
        i++;
    //redeclaring int i to 0 for the (part e)
    i = 0;
    //removing every occurance of 'f' (part e)
    while (i < sLength) {
        if (newArray[i] == 'f'  ) {
            newArray[i] = ' ';
        }
        i++;
    //printing to console
    }
    sentence = new String(newArray);
    System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

}

Comment: I apologise the real output is: "There was a isherman named []isher who ished or some ish in a issure; till a ish with a grin, pulled the isherman in. Now they’re ishing the issure or []isher."

Comment: Edit your question accordingly, you can do so; also, what Java version is that?

Comment: Not clear why you need `positionArray`. Just replace the characters directly in the `char[]`.

Comment: I am so new to java I have no idea, I use netbeans if that helps? Also, thanks, I edited the OP.

Comment: @AndyTurner this will be OK as long as said `char`s are not outside of the BMP but then it can be assumed that this will be the case...

Comment: Also, what is supposed to happen if you find an `f` in the input string? Should it also become `0` or should it be left as is?

Comment: I have changed that andy, thankyou! Made it much tidier without that extra useless array. Any thoughts of the capital F's turning into [] when i'm only targeting 'f'?

Comment: I think I've just overwhelmed myself, last week I was writing "hello world" this is too much for me I think haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using Java 8. It uses the fact that a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), and that you can obtain an [IntStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of either the characters or code points in it; this solution uses [chars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--):

```
// Turn all 'F's into 'f's
private int bigFToSmallF(final int inputChar)
{
    return 'F' == inputChar ? 'f' : inputChar;
}

// Turn all 'f's into '0's
private int smallFToZero(final int inputChar)
{
    return 'f' == inputChar ? '0' : inputChar;
}

private String anyFToZeroes(final String input)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());

    input.chars().map(this::bigFToSmallF).map(this::smallFToZero)
        .forEach(sb::appendCodePoint);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Plug this code into a `main` and you're done.

Comment: You are amazing, I will study this thoroughly, I seriously can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

No errors for me. Works fine in win cmd and in eclipse. I had a similar problem some time ago. For me the issue was that there was an error in my installed fonts. Just some Win update has currupted something, don't know why. After I manually reinstalled my std fonts everything worked fine. Additionally to the problem also was within the "space". When I checked the hex value in debug view, the value was slightely off and so a different character was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code indentation.
Your idea is correct, although is not optimized.

You've implemented 3 loops, but the last while is a inner loop.
I think you wanted to implement 3 'independent' loops, check out the brackets placement.